# Построение выражения для получения элемента массива

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Вообщем требуется превратить `#$test.a#` в `$test['a']`.

Делаю это так: `preg_replace('@\#(\$.+?)\.(.+?)\#@', '$1[\'$2\']', '#$test.a#', -1);`

Всё работает: https://xrg.es/#1ibiack

Но не знаю как превратить `#$test.a.b.c#` в `$test['a']['b']['c']`.

Помогите... Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *не знаю как превратить #$test.a.b.c# в $test['a']['b']['c']*

Вначале найти совпадения подстроки между решётками `'#...#'`. Потом разбить найденную подстроку на элементы по символу `'.'`. Далее, из полученного массива извлечь первый элемент *(это название переменной)*, а оставшуюся часть обработать циклом, собирая строку необходимого формата в результирующую переменную `$out`:

```
$str = '#$test.a.b.c#'; // Сработает
$str = '#$test.a#';     // Сработает
$str = '#$test.#';      // Не сработает
$str = '#$test#';       // Не сработает

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~#(\$[a-z]+\d*\.[^#]+)#~',
    function ($arr) {
        $tmp = explode('.', $arr[1]);
        $out = array_shift($tmp);
        foreach ($tmp as $i) $out .= "['$i']";
        $out .= ';';
        return $out;
    },
    $str
);
```

Результат

```
$test['a']['b']['c'];
```

---

Следует помнить, что полученная строка не является массивом, а только выглядит как массив визуально.

Comment: Спасибо работает отлично, ещё маленький вопрос: Как сделать чтобы совпадение было только если есть точка? Имеется ввиду: #test.a# === true; $test === false. То есть чтобы не обрабатывалось если отсутствует ключ массива.

Comment: @VadimPedchenko чуть позже подправлю шаблон с учётом ваших предпочтений.

Answer (score 3):

Всё можно сделать одной регуляркой с использованием оператора `\G`:

```
'~(?:#(\$[^.#]+)(?=\.[^#]*#)|\G(?!^))\.([^#.]+)#?~'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/tAbjlX/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?:#(\$[^.#]+)(?=\.[^#]*#)|\G(?!^))` - одно из двух:

  - `#(\$[^.#]+)(?=\.[^#]*#)` - последовательность:

    - `#` - знак `#`,
    - `(\$[^.#]+)` - Захватывающая группа №1: `$`, один и более символов, отличных от `.` и `#`
    - `(?=\.[^#]*#)` - после которых есть знак `.`, 0+ знаков, отличных от `#`, а затем `#`
  - `|` - или
  - `\G(?!^)` - позиция в строке после предыдущего удачного совпадения
- `\.` - знак `.`
- `([^#.]+)` - Захватывающая группа №2: 1+ знаков, отличных от `.` и `#`
- `#?` - 1 или 0 знаков `#`.

[Пример на PHP](https://ideone.com/BvpkVP):

```
$re = '@(?:#(\$[^.#]+)(?=\.[^#]*#)|\G(?!^))\.([^#.]+)#?@';
$str = '#$test.a.b.c# #$test.a#';
echo preg_replace($re, '$1[\'$2\']', $str);
// => $test['a']['b']['c'] $test['a']
```

Comment: а разве есть в пхп модификатор `\G` ? И ещё вопрос -
 можно ли подставить `;` ?

Comment: @Эдуард В PCRE есть поддержка оператора `\G`. А куда надо подставить `;`? В вопросе нет такого требования.

Comment: про `\G` в [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) я ничего не видел O.o ... А точку с запятой - в конце каждого "массива". Хотя в первом посту я сейчас этого не вижу, может быть и не нужно. UPD: да, точку с запятой надо в конец массива, как [тут](https://xrg.es/#1ibiack)

Comment: [Документация по PCRE тут](https://pcre.org/pcre.txt). В PHP используется именно эта библиотека. А в вопросе всё-таки нет требования добавить `;`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, Вопрос: как быть если нужно заменить например на: array $1[\'$2\'] array, тогда слово array будет повторяться после каждого ключа: https://xrg.es/#1qb7paf

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew почитал про `\G` - ___начало совпадения, или конец предыдущего совпадения___. Но этот модификатор, если не ошибаюсь, используется в Perl? Кстати, без него ваш шаблон тоже отрабатывает, поэтому я не понимаю целесообразность его использования. Не могли бы вы пояснить?

Comment: @Эдуард `\G` = начало строки или конец предыдущего совпадения. Да, этот оператор присутствует в регулярных выражениях Perl, а также Ruby, .NET, Java. "Работает" выражение с ним по-другому нежели [без него](https://regex101.com/r/lPJwSg/1). `\G` находит совпадения одно за другим, между ними не должно быть текста. А блок просмотра вперёд гарантирует, что найден именно текст между `$#` и `#`.

Comment: @VadimPedchenko При данном подходе находится и заменяется несколько совпадений, а не одно. Находится `$#test.a`, потом `.b`, потос `.c`. Нельзя просто так добавить текст с одного и другого края. Тут помогут только средства самого PHP: [`$res = "array " . preg_replace(....) . " array";`](https://ideone.com/kiODA7).

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

```
preg_replace("@\#(\$.+?)\.(.+?)\.(.+?)\.(.+?)\#@", "$1['$2']['$3']['$4'];", "#$test.a.b.c#", -1);
```

PS. Но если там может быть разное количество переменных, то это будет сложнее сделать.

Answer (score 0):

За входние данные можно взять

```
$string = '#$test_23.a.b.c#';
```

Напишу небольшую функцию которая будет делать то что нужно и возвращать результат или FALSE если будут невалидные данные

Для  начала проверим что слева действительно валидное название переменной.

Оно как известно начинаеться со знака доллара ($)
Потом должна идти одна буква латинского алфавита или нижнее подчеркивание ([a-zA-Z_])

Дальше в названии переменной может идти любая цифра, буква латинского алфавита или знак подчеркивания (\w). Символ * указывает на то что их может быть 0 или больше. Тоесть их может и не быть.

Справа может быть или не быть продолжение название переменной

```
function transform($string){
  if(preg_match('@#(\$[a-zA-Z_]\w*)\.?([\w.]+)?#@', $string, $match)){
      if(empty($match[2])){
        return $match[1];       
      }
      $replace_string = "['" . preg_replace('@(\w)\.@', "$1']['", $match[2]) . "']";
      return $match[1] . $replace_string;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```